# Is $i: (C^1, ||·||_{W^{1,2}}) → (C^0, ||·||_∞)$ a linear, continuous, compact map?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Consider the map 
>   $$i:  (C^1[0,1], ||·||_{W^{1,2}}) → (C^0[0,1], ||·||_∞)$$
>   which maps every function to itself, and with Sobolev norm defined as
>   $$||u||_{W^{1,2}}=||u||_{L^2}+||u'||_{L^2}.$$
>   Is $i$ linear, continuous, compact?

**Linearity**

Consider $u,v\in C^1[0,1]$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$:

$i(au+bv)=au+bv=ai(u)+bi(v)$

**Continuity**

By fundamental theorem of calculus: $u(x)=u(0)+\int_0^x u'(t)dt$. Then:

$\begin{align*}
|u(x)| &\le |u(0)|+\int_0^x |u'(t)|dt \\
&\le |u(0)|+\int_0^1 |u'(t)|dt \\
&\le C|u(0)|^2+C\int_0^1 |u'(t)|^2dt \\
&\le C\int_0^1 |u(t)|^2dt+C\int_0^1 |u'(t)|^2dt \\
&\le C(||u||_{L^2}+||u'||_{L^2}) \\
&=C||u||_{W^{1,2}}
\end{align*}$

for $C$ large enough and by mean value theorem.

Since $i$ is linear and bounded, it is also continuous.

**Compactness**

$i$ is defined on an infinite-dimensional space, so by Riesz theorem the closed unit ball $B$ is not compact. If the dual norm of $i$ would be $1$, then we could say that $i(B)\subseteq B$, and so also $i$ would not be compact. But in this exercise I cannot show this is the case.

Are the computations for linearity and continuity correct?

How to check the compactness?

Comment: Do you know the Ascoli theorem?

Comment: It says that if a sequence $u_n$ of continuous functions is equicontinuous, then $u_n$ has a subsequence which converge uniformly. Right?

Comment: The sequence must also be bounded, but right. So prove the unit ball in your origin space is bounded in $C^0$ and equicontinuous.

Comment: But $C^0$ is infinite-dimensional, so the unit ball is not compact, right?

Comment: The unit ball of $C^0$ for the $C^0$ norm is not. However, a smaller set (such as the unit ball of $C^1$ for the $H^1$ norm) could be compact for the $C^0$ norm.

Comment: I don't understand, "could" be compact?

Comment: Could, as in : not forbidden by Riesz theorem.

Comment: Ok, so how can we check if the unit ball of $C^1$ it is compact or not for the $C^0$ norm? I'm struggling with this

Comment: As the answer (not from me) explains, try and use Ascoli’s theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compactness it has to be shown that a bounded set is relatively compact.
Now let $G$ be a bounded set, i.e. there is an $M$ such that for all $f \in G$ it holds $ ||f||_{L^2} + ||f'||_{L^2} \le M$.

If we can show now that all elements of $G$ satisfy a uniform Hölder condition (see Arzela-Ascoli theorem in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Lipschitz_and_H%C3%B6lder_continuous_functions) then the set is relatively compact and we are done.

And in fact : Let $a, b \in [0,1]$, and $f \in G $. Then we have $ |f(a)-f(b)| = |\int_a^b f' | = |\int_a^b (f' \times 1) | \le ||f'||_{L^2[a,b]} ||1||_{L^2[a,b]} = ||f'||_{L^2[a,b]}|a-b|^{1/2} \le ||f'||_{L^2}|a-b|^{1/2} \le M|a-b|^{1/2}.$

So Arzela-Ascoli is applicable and we have proven the requested property.

**For continuity** as $i$ is linear, then $i$ is continuous iff there is a constant $C$ such that for all $u$ it holds $||u||_\infty \le C (||u||_{L^2}+||u'||_{L^2})$.
Now let us pick some $u$. Then there is a $r\in [0,1]$ where $u^2$ attains its minimum. And $|u|$ attains its minimum in $r$ as well. This $r$ is clearly dependant on $u$. But for any $x\in [0,1]$ we have $|u(x)| = |\int^x_r u'(t)dt +u(r)| \le |\int^x_r u'(t)dt| +|u(r)| = |\int^x_r u'(t) \times 1 dt| +|\int_0^1 |u(r)| \times 1 dt| \le ||u'||_{L^2} + |\int_0^1 |u(t)| \times 1 dt|\le ||u'||_{L^2} + ||u||_{L^2}$

Thus $C=1$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you also say if the computation about continuity is correct?

Comment: Linearity is Ok, but the way you show the continuity seems not ok. E.g. the constant $C$ is dependant on the choice of $u$.

Comment: But for every $u$ you can find another constant, right? Otherwise what would be the proper way to show the continuity?

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: Thank you, but why is important to take $r$ to be the minimum of $u^2$ and of $|u|$?

Comment: That is needed for the inequality $|\int_0^1 |u(r)| \times 1 dt| \le |\int_0^1 |u(t)| \times 1 dt|$. Note that the first integrand is **constant** but the second is not.

Comment: Why does $|u(r)| = |\int_0^1 |u(r)|dt|$ hold?

Comment: $|u(r)| =|u(r)| \times (1-0) = |u(r)|\int_0^1 dt= \int_0^1 |u(r)| dt =|\int_0^1 |u(r)| dt|$